# Tries to create a Win32 project that can use WinUI3

Tags: c++, xaml, winapi, winui-3

EDIT: I found it. It's based on [this code](https://github.com/sotanakamura/winui3-without-midl) and I describe it in my article [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5359576/WinUI3-in-Existing-Win32-Applications).

---

This is a post of my ideas and hoping to get yours from the WinUI3 <-> Win32 relationship. The idea is to create a plain Win32 project that also has WinUI3 capabilities (without the buggy XAML islands which are not WinUI3 anyway).

Up to date, the only thing I have managed is to create an unpacked WinUI3 executable that will intercommunicate with a normal Win32 executable so to show some WinUI3 dialogs. Of course, this is bothersome for I have to manually intercommunicate via shared memory/ mutexes etc. My full article on this is [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5359576/WinUI3-in-Existing-Win32-Applications).

[image]

I'm trying either to start from a working WinUI3 project and to render it a plain Win32 application, or start from a plain Win32 application and render it to a WinUI3-capable project. The idea is to be able to find out at runtime when WinUI3 is available and if not, the application still runs under Windows 7, for example.

When starting from a running, unpackaged WinUI3 app (called "w" from now on), I 've noticed that in the .vcxproj this line exists:

```
<ApplicationType>Windows Store</ApplicationType>
```

The XAML file "App.xaml" in that  project is compiled automatically to generate 'App.xaml.g.h'. When this ApplicationType line is removed, VS fails to generate these .g files.

When starting from the Win32 project (called "c" from now on) and adding this , it practically does nothing. In this project after using NuGet to add the WindowsAppSDK I've tried:

Using the bootstrap:

```
CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
PACKAGE_VERSION pg = {};
auto hr = MddBootstrapInitialize(WINDOWSAPPSDK_RELEASE_MAJORMINOR, L"", pg);
if (FAILED(hr))
    return 0;
```

This works OK so far. Then I saw loading the App.xaml in the "w" project and I'm trying to do that in the "c" project:

```
struct App : public winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Application
{
    App()
    {
        winrt::Windows::Foundation::Uri resourceLocator{ L"f:\\wui3tests\\c\\app.xaml" };
        winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Application::LoadComponent(*this, resourceLocator);

    }

};
```

In the "w" project it's

```
::winrt::Windows::Foundation::Uri resourceLocator{ L"ms-appx:///App.xaml" };
::winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Application::LoadComponent(*this, resourceLocator);
```

What's this ms-appx://App.xaml ? How it is stored in the executable? (not as resource).

In any case, line   `winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Application::LoadComponent(*this, resourceLocator);` fails with a "wrong thread" exception.

Let's say I don't call LoadComponent, I also tried disabling it in the "w" app and it runs fine. Now I try to create a Window:

```
struct MainWindow : public winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Window
{
    MainWindow() : winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Window(nullptr)
    {

    }
};
```

This also throws a 0 read (invalid pointer exception).

I also tried to convert the "w" project into a DLL which exports a function to be called by "c". This time the "w" project fails no matter whether the bootstrapper API is called or not (throws exception in Load).

In short, I'm dead stuck. Is it any point going further? The "bootstrapper" API seems useless, even the [MS demo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/tutorial-unpackaged-deployment?tabs=cpp) only shows how to call it and then it does a std::cout to the console project, no windows whatsoever.

Comment: ms-appx will load xaml compiled as a binary file (.xbf extension), so App.xbf in App.xaml case (format is not documented). You might want to look at this test project which loads w/o xaml: https://github.com/sotanakamura/winui3-without-xaml/blob/master/main.cpp maybe not so far to what you're trying to do

Comment: @SimonMourier thanks a lot, I'm very close. I've successfully built a XAML EXEcutable, now I'm trying to build a DLL.
`Application::LoadComponent(window, Uri(L"ms-appx:///MainPage.xaml"));` 
This line fails, probably because it eventually calls GetModuleHandle(0) which returns the handle of the EXE, not the DLL. Any way I can override that?

Comment: You could try to [use the WinRT XAML hosting API in a C++ desktop (Win32) app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/using-the-xaml-hosting-api)

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT it is buggy. However, I managed to make it. Will soon post an article on that.